# PowerShell でフォルダ内の"それぞれ"最新ファイルを取得したい｡

Tags: powershell

PowerShellでフォルダ､ファイル操作のスクリプトを書いているのですが､賢い書き方をご存じであればご教授ください｡

あるフォルダの中には以下のようなファイルが存在します｡

**Test-A001.txt 2017/04/18**
Test-A001_old.txt 2017/04/10
**Test-B001_最新.txt 2017/04/19**
Test-B001.txt 2017/04/11
**Test-C001.txt 2017/04/18**
Test-C001_20170417.txt 2017/04/17

この中から､日付が新しい「Test-A|B|C」を取得したい｡
取得したファイルリストは以下の通りです｡

**Test-A001.txt 2017/04/18

Test-B001_最新.txt 2017/04/19

Test-C001.txt 2017/04/18**

よろしくお願いします｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「Test-A|B|C」が固定長かつ先頭から始まることが保証されているなら、下記のコードで取れます。

```
$len = "Test-X".Length # グループ化する文字数(6文字)
$gp = ls | %{$_.Name.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($_.Name.Length, $len))} | group
$ss = $gp | %{ $s=$_.Name + "*"; ls -Filter $s | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select -First 1 }
$ss
```

ファイル名の部分文字列をグループ化して、それぞれのグルーブに対して更新日付でソートをかけて最新のファイルを取得します。

Comment: 迅速な返信ありがとうございます｡ 求めている事ができました｡　大変助かりました｡１つ質問なのですが､コマンド内の"Test-X"と記載がありますが､ "-X"はどういう意味なのでしょうか｡

Comment: payaneco様　上の質問ですが､-Xに特に意味はなく.Lengthの値取得のために-Xと記載しただけだったんですね｡｡　理解しました｡

Comment: ちなみに変数に上記結果を代入しようとすると､Exceptionが出てしまいます｡Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.　　代入しなければ期待結果になるのですが､代入ができません… 基本的な質問で申し訳ございませんがご教授ください｡｡

Comment: "Test-X"の意図はお見込みの通りです。定数を直接指定しても問題ありません。手元の環境では変数に収めてもエラーが発生しませんでした。エラー内容を見ると、Substringでエラーが出ているようです。(例えば"abc".Substring(0, 4)を実行すると同様のエラーが表示されると思われます。修正後のスクリプトは正常に動作するでしょうか

Comment: Substringの中にminで最小を入れるようにしたのですね｡修正後のスクリプトで正常に動くようになりました｡　恐らくですが､原因は実行しているps1ファイル自体のファイル名がtest.ps1みたいに短いためだったかと思います｡(消してしまったので再現確認できてませんが…)